how to connect excel sheet in sharepoint by nodejs
I have this code to download and upload excel sheet to microsoft sharepoint but seems it's not working due to some version issues or something other.Is there other way to connect to sharepoint with username and password instead of "<client_id>", "<client_secret>", "<tenant_id>")?
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";
import { NodeFetchClient } from "@pnp/nodejs"; // Updated import
import xlsx from "xlsx";
import fs from "fs";

// SharePoint setup
sp.setup({
  sp: {
    fetchClientFactory: () => new NodeFetchClient("<client_id>", "<client_secret>", "<tenant_id>"),
    baseUrl: "<sharepoint_site_url>", // Example: https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site
  },
});

// Function to upload Excel file to SharePoint
async function uploadExcel(filePath, libraryName, fileName) {
  try {
    const fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
    await sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(libraryName).files.add(fileName, fileBuffer, true);
    console.log("File uploaded successfully!");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error uploading file:", err);
  }
}

// Function to download Excel file from SharePoint
async function downloadExcel(libraryName, fileName, downloadPath) {
  try {
    const file = await sp.web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(`${libraryName}/${fileName}`).getBuffer();
    fs.writeFileSync(downloadPath, file);
    console.log("File downloaded successfully!");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error downloading file:", err);
  }
}

// Example Usage
const filePath = "example.xlsx";
const libraryName = "Shared Documents"; // Change as needed
const fileName = "example.xlsx";
const downloadPath = "downloaded_example.xlsx";

// Upload and Download
(async () => {
  await uploadExcel(filePath, libraryName, fileName);
  await downloadExcel(libraryName, fileName, downloadPath);
})();


You just need to use AuthConfig if you want to go down that approach - however tokens are a safer way to be doing this, passwords may be reset at any point and if you start hammering login with incorrect username and password with this script you may end up locking the user out. If you can use a token.
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";
import { SPFetchClient } from "@pnp/nodejs"; // Updated import
import xlsx from "xlsx";
import fs from "fs";
import { AuthConfig } from "sp-auth";

// SharePoint setup
(async () => {
  try {
    // Authentication setup with username and password
    const authConfig = new AuthConfig({
      username: "<your_username>",
      password: "<your_password>",
      siteUrl: "<sharepoint_site_url>", // Example: https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site
    });

    const context = await authConfig.getContext();

    sp.setup({
      sp: {
        fetchClientFactory: () => new SPFetchClient(context.siteUrl, context.authOptions),
        baseUrl: context.siteUrl,
      },
    });

    console.log("SharePoint authentication setup completed.");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error setting up authentication:", err);
  }
})();

// Function to upload Excel file to SharePoint
async function uploadExcel(filePath, libraryName, fileName) {
  try {
    const fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
    await sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(libraryName).files.add(fileName, fileBuffer, true);
    console.log("File uploaded successfully!");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error uploading file:", err);
  }
}

// Function to download Excel file from SharePoint
async function downloadExcel(libraryName, fileName, downloadPath) {
  try {
    const file = await sp.web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(`${libraryName}/${fileName}`).getBuffer();
    fs.writeFileSync(downloadPath, file);
    console.log("File downloaded successfully!");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error downloading file:", err);
  }
}


hi, this module "sp-auth" seem deprecated unable to install @Ryan McDonough
